# use-yarn thinks I'm not using yarn

Tags: node.js, npm, yarnpkg, nvm, npx

I have an app that uses yarn. I was having trouble with a `yarn install...` script. I tried a bunch of things, including using nvm to switch node versions. After that, I had a bunch of yarns installed and was still seeing the same unrelated issue (network issue pulling a dependency). So, I decided to switch back to the latest version of node and try something else. But, that introduced a new issue.

The yarn script stopped working completely. I'm using `yarn install:deps` and the result is to first run the `preinstall` script which does `npx use-yarn` and that errors and blocks continuation of the script. It says I'm not using yarn, though my command is `yarn install:deps` and `which yarn` shows that I am indeed running yarn.

How do you fix this?